# Problem: This Oracle software is not certified on the current operating system while installing weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

Expected result: One of 6.0,6.1,6.2
Actual Result: 6.3
Check complete. 
The overall result of this check is: Failed

Problem: This Oracle software is not certified on the current operating system.
Recommendation: Make sure you are installing the software on the correct platform.

I am facing this error while installing web logic on windows 10. Java version is JDK7.I have already setup class path (JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME) but unable to install. Please help me to solve.

Comment: Which WebLogic Server version are you trying to install ?

Comment: Oracle WebLogic Server 12.1.3

Comment: can you post the complete error message from the installer ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jgDURSFm

Comment: You can try to run the installer with the -ignoreSysPrereqs flag to by-pass the issue.